# iPhone / iPad IOS File Permissions / SandBox anyway to give permissions to another app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, file, file-permissions

Is there anyway to "break" the sandbox and give permissions to another running APP to allow for file access read / write / delete for the other APP?  I did a bit of looking and have not found a way yet.

Comment: There isn't. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Well, there are two applications that I am trying to solve.  One is a sister testing runtime app that would test another app at run time by removing files, etc to make sure it is working.  Another one is for two apps to share the same file for some sort of data transfer.  Might have to look at different ways of doing this.  Did not want to jail break to do this, but might have to or move to a host system for the testing.  I know, can also use the xcode testing suite, may have to look at this also, but wanted a sister app to do this.

Comment: For testing you could use regular unit tests or test in the simulator (it doesn't enforce sandboxing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a normal iOS device this is not possible.

On a jailbroken device, use NSFileManager. It gives you full access to the filesystem — just give it the paths you want to mess with. You can get the contents of a directory with its -`contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` method and move files around with -`moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:`

For more - [Apple iOS Runtime Environment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html)